# showAuthenticationDialog not closing popup on windows

Tags: javascript, facebook, spotify

We're writing a spotify app which uses the showAuthenticationDialog-Dialog for inviting users facebook friends.

Inviting works, but the Popup-Windows doesn't close on Windows (on a Mac it does!).

The Code looks like that:

```
    var redir = "https://server/services/callback/facebook/apprequest/?source=spotify&user_id=" + uID;

    var data = "user_id=" + session.otheruser.id;
    var url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?app_id=" + FB_APP_ID + "&message=" + encodeURIComponent( msg ) + "&redirect_uri=" + encodeURIComponent( redir ) + "&display=popup&data=" + encodeURIComponent( data ); 

    auth.showAuthenticationDialog(url, 'http://moosify.com', {
        onSuccess : function(response) {
            console.log("Success! Here's the response URL: " + response);
        },

        onFailure : function(error) {
            console.log("Authentication failed with error: " + error);
        },

        onComplete : function() { }
    });
```

Server is acutally our server URL. (Which is in the manifest.json)

Comment: Do the correct callbacks get fired?

Comment: No it doesn't. Stupid minimal comment limit.